# Cannot access D drive

Tags: mount, ntfs

Today I did a clean ubuntu installation by removing window 8 from my laptop. I thought that after installing ubuntu I will have no problem in acessing D drive, where i have all my important data.But now I am unable to mount D drive. it gives following error.

```
ror mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/nitesh/data: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda5" "/media/nitesh/data"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Now I dont have window 8 also to resume and shutdown
Windows fully.now Is there any solution for it?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.

go to windows.use check disk tool:
open run , type cmd , use this command:

CHKDSK D:/

that will work.

in ubuntu you can use this article:
[check disk in ubuntu](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-corrupted-windows-ntfs-filesystem-ubuntu/%2a)

Comment: i think he doesn't had windows.